# Computing connection forms using Cartan's structure equation for torsion forms

Tags: differential-geometry

From $\theta^i = (1-\phi)dx^i$, $d\theta^i \approx \partial_j\phi\;\theta^i\wedge\theta^j$, I'm supposed to obtain $w^i_j = -\partial_j\phi\;\theta^i + \partial_i\phi\;\theta^j$ using $w^i_j \wedge \theta^j = -d\theta^i$.

By comparing the two expressions, I only get the first term. How do I get both?

Comment: Probably through an antisymmetry argument.

Comment: The connection for the structural equation $d\theta^{i}$ at the beginning needs to be anti-symmetric. Also, $d\theta^i +w^i_j \wedge \theta^j=0$ appears to be a torsion-less connection. If there was torsion, I would expect $d\theta^i +w^i_j \wedge \theta^j=\tau^{i}$ where $\tau$ is the torsion $2$-form. But it is possible to have torsion and have a torsion-less connection. And it's possible there is torsion but I just don't see it.